# Node/Express/Jade style guides?

Tags: node.js, coding-style, express, pug

I'm coming over from PHP where the convention is to use 4 space tabs. I've noticed that in a lot of examples (and project bootstrap code) 2 spaces is used. I haven't been able to find definitive style guides that mention spacing for these projects so I'm wondering if this is actually the convention.

Comment: No. It can be a convention within some projects (e.g. Bootstrap's current  [Coding Standards](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.0-rc1/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding-standards)), but there aren't any actual conventions held by the languages themselves.

Comment: It is not a language requirement but is being used pretty often. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Let me start by saying - according to the requirements of the language (**Javascript**) the 2 spaces are **NOT REQUIRED** (infact most of the times you can get away without using a `;` too at the end). **However** if you mean to ask whether people use it ? Then here is the answer :

For **Node** - it starts from [here](https://github.com/ry) so the **creator** of Node (and also maintainer and BDFL) !! ([Ryan-Dahl](http://nodeguide.com/community.html#ryan-dahl) aka the "benevolent dictator") insisted on using the 2 spaces . Ofcourse he is the creator so everybody has a tendency to follow.

> Tabs vs Spaces
>
> Let's start with the religious problems first. Our benevolent dictator has chosen 2 space indention for the node core, so you would do well to follow his choice.

Then comes [TJ Holowaychuk](https://github.com/visionmedia) author of **Express, Jade**, Stylus, and Mocha quoted from [here](http://dailyjs.com/2012/01/12/style/)

> has an extremely consistent style. TJ uses two spaces for indentation, semicolons to end lines, and formats commas at the start of a new line:

Then there is [Isaac Z. Schlueter](https://github.com/isaacs),author of ***npm** !!*

Even on the [Jade reference page](http://jade-lang.com/reference/) ... all the code more or less has 2 spaces.

So it is a better thing to adopt the practice and it is **almost in all major projects of Node/Express/Jade**.

**But IMHO who cares as long as you are confident that your code is correct. Maybe one day you will write better and *elegant* code and become the "benevolent dictator" ;-).**

Hope that answers the question :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and references.

Answer (score 2):

Find the below urls this can be helpful if you are new to these:
http://jade-lang.com/api/

http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/

http://expressjs.com/guide.html